# Customizing email_confirmation_message.txt of allauth django project gives error what to do?

Tags: django, django-allauth

Invalid block tag on line 7: 'endblocktrans', expected 'endautoescape'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

```
{% load account %}{% user_display user as user_display %}{% load i18n %}\
{% autoescape off %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name
site_domain=current_site.domain %}Hi from {{ site_name }}!
You're receiving this e-mail because user {{ user_display }} has given
yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.
To confirm this is correct, go to {{ activate_url }}
{% endblocktrans %}{% endautoescape %}
{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site\
.domain %}Thank you from {{ site_name }}!
{{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

[image]

Comment: I faced the same issue while following `Django for professionals` book, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try ?

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load account %}

{% user_display user as user_display %}

{% autoescape off %}

    {% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}

    Hi from {{ site_name }}!
    You are receiving this e-mail because user {{ user_display }} has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.
    To confirm this is correct, go to {{ activate_url }}

    {% endblocktrans %}

    {% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}
    Thank you from {{ site_name }}!
    {{ site_domain }}

    {% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```